# Имеет ли смысл использование ORM фрэймворков вне web приложений?

Tags: веб-программирование, orm

Имеет ли смысл использование ORM фрэймворков вне web приложений?

Comment: у вас есть веские доводы против использования ORM в десктопных приложениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно имеет.

Если у вас в проекте нет каких то супер-сложных связей между таблицами, то почему бы и не использовать? Обратиться к атрибуту объекта иногда гораздо быстрее и проще, чем писать для этого SQL запрос.